# Combine second column in the first and display it horizontally

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I have two columns in a list. One Column contains questions and the other column contains radio buttons.

I want to display the radio button options horizontally and below the questions.

Currently, It is being display vertically and in the other column.

Is this possible?

The current view is shown below.

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to infopath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your base requirement is to have a survey kind of thing you may create a Survey list using OOTB Survey template.

Else if you wish to have the Question and Radio buttons horizontally in a custom list you have to apply CSS styles using JavaScript in the NewForm.aspx & EditForm.aspx page.

Try the below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function(){
var question = $("td.ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader nobr:contains('COLUMNNAME')").parent().parent().parent();
question.find('span table tr').css('display','table-cell');
question.find('span table tr').css('padding-right','5px');
question.find('span table tr span').css('display','inline-flex');
question.css('display','table');
question.find("td.ms-formlabel").css('display','table-header-group');
});
</script>
```

Replace the COLUMNNAME token in the above script with the display name of the field.

Steps to add the code:

1. Open NewForm.aspx page
2. Edit the page in browser
3. Add a script editor webpart
4. Add the above script in the webpart
5. Save the page
6. Do the same in EditForm.aspx page

Comment: Thank you for sharing your views. I want it in custom list only. Can you please help me with the code. I am new in sharepoint

Comment: modified the answer as per your requirement.

Comment: Hi Nagarajan, I cant find the column name.. Can you help me with it

Comment: Column name token is present in the third line of the code. Replace that with your column display name.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use SharePoint Designer to create a custom NewForm.  By default, the list will be arranged in a table format, with each question being in a `tr`, with the question and answer in their own `td`.  Either break it out of a table, or put the question and answer in different `tr`.  As for arranging the choice options horizontally, [this](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/11/arrange-choice-field-radio-buttons-horizontally-in-sharepoint.html) blog post has instructions on how to do so (requires `jQuery`).

From the aforementioned blog:

1. First wrap the choice field in a `span` tag and give it an id.  E.g.,

   `<span id="optReqType">
       <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff3{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Change_x0020_Request_x0020_Type"
   __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff3',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Change_x0020_Request_x0020_Type')}"/>
       <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff3description{$Pos}" FieldName="Change_x0020_Request_x0020_Type" ControlMode="New"/> 
   </span>`
2. Then create a function to arrange them horizontally:

   `$(document).ready(function() {
       var firstRadio = $("#optReqType table tbody tr td .ms-RadioText:eq(0)");
       $("#optReqType table tbody tr td .ms-RadioText:gt(0)").appendTo($(firstRadio));
   });`

You can wrap the code in a function if you have multiple choice fields.

And if someone can fix the formatting, I'd appreciate it.  Not sure why it's not working right for me...